# Problem installing/running Erlang OTP: Cannot find entry point for llround in beam.smp.dll

Tags: installation, dll, erlang

We use Erlang OTP because it is bundled with a business application my company uses (as part of a RabbitMQ installation).  On our development and test servers, the entire installation went smoothly without any issues.  On the production system, however, Erlang OTP installs but fails to launch afterwards.  When I doubleclick `erl.exe` I get an error popup:

> The entry point “llround” was not found in the DLL “C:\Program Files (x86)\…\Erlang-21.3\erts-10.3\bin\beam.smp.dll”. *(Translated from German, path clipped)*

I am completely new to Erlang, so I do not even know whether there are any logs that I should provide.  In the Erlang directory, I cannot find anything that looks like a log.  The Windows event log shows basically the abovementioned error message plus a message saying that the Erlang VM crashed instantly (wrong distribution name?) – but that seems to be just a follow-up to the root cause of the problem with the DLL.

As I said, `erl.exe` opens without problems and displays a command prompt when launched on the test or development system.  The setup there is almost identical to our production server.  We tried removing Erlang and reinstalling it but to no avail.  We even restored the VM to an earlier point an did a fresh install of the entire application.  Short of setting up another pristine VM, is there any way of getting Erlang to work on the existing system?

Comment: You have you tried https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#installer ?

Comment: @2240 Yes, tried that.  We ensured that erlang is installed as admin.  It's not the problem that rabbitmq doesn't work, but erlang itself is already broken.